# Button does not navigate to desired screen and shows undefined object error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build an app which would contain 4 buttons and each one of them would lead to a new screen, But whenever I try to click any button it shows `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.props.navigation.navigate')
onPress Buttons.js:21:57`. When I click the `flood` button it should navigate to flood page where it shows only text `flood`. I am new to react native any want to write clean and modular code. What should be a great directory structure?

Directory Structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiEgk.jpg
Error - https://i.stack.imgur.com/azftz.jpg

`APP.js`

```
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, StatusBar} from 'react-native';
import SubmitButton from "./src/components/SubmitButton";
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);
import Navigator from "./Navigator";
import Buttons from "./Buttons"

export default class Indra extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
         <Buttons navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
         <Navigator /> 
         <SubmitButton />
      </View>
    );
  }
}


`Navigator.js`
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Flood from "./src/screens/Flood";
import Rain from "./src/screens/Rain";


const Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    Flood: { screen: Flood },
    Rain: { screen: Rain },

});

const NavigatorApp = createAppContainer(Navigator);
export default NavigatorApp;

Buttons.js
import Flood from "./src/screens/Flood";
import Rain from "./src/screens/Rain";
import {
    View,
    Button,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Buttons extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Button
                    title="Flood"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Flood')}
                    color = 'blue'
                />
                <Button
                    title="Rain"
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Rain')}
                    color = 'red'
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

Flood.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    Button,
    Alert,
} from 'react-native';

export default class Flood extends Component {
    render() {
        onPressFlood = () => {
            Alert.alert(" Flood ");
        }
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>FLOOD</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working because `Indra` is not part of the navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Indra` is not part of your navigation, add it to your navigation routes.

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Flood from "./src/screens/Flood";
import Rain from "./src/screens/Rain";
import Indra from './src/screens/Indra';

const Navigator = createStackNavigator(
{
    Flood: Flood,
    Rain: Rain,
    Indra: Indra,
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Indra'
}
);

export default Navigator;
```

Remove `Navigator` from `Indra`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { YellowBox, View } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
'Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated',
'Module RCTImageLoader',
]);
import Buttons from './Buttons';

export default class Indra extends Component {
render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <Buttons navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    </View>
    );
}
}
```

In your `App.js`

```
import React, {
Component
} from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Navigator from "./Navigator";

export default createAppContainer(Navigator);
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/navigation)

Comment: Thank You very much. That worked. What is the ideal directory structure for an RN project? Why was it not working earlier can you explain a little bit.

Comment: the navigation prop is passed to components that use react-navigation,if the component is not part of it, it won't get that prop, that's why you were getting undefined.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass navigation props `this.props.navigation` to Buttons Component, but the navigation props does not exist there. 
`this.props.navigation` can only be used for Screens and Components inside the stack navigator(Navigator.js). So, you can use `this.props.navigation` in `Flood` or `Rain` screen.